# How can I get this Search Bar style in react-native-element?

Tags: react-native, styles, stylesheet

It's basically the search bar component from react-native-elements where the container background color is white and the placeholder field has a border with radius.

Not sure if react-native-element allows providing style to placeholder.
Any other way i could use style along with react-native-elements search bar component to get this result?

[image]

Comment: You dont need to modify the placeholder, since styles for it are not available, instead you can modify your inputStyles

Comment: Did you manage to style the search? Using `1.1.0` I cant get any styles to work

Answer (score 19):

You need to modify the [`input`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar/#containerstyle) and [`container`](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar/#containerstyle) styles

```
 <SearchBar
    inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5}}
    placeholderTextColor={'#g5g5g5'}
    placeholder={'Pritish Vaidya'}
/>
```

Check the [docs](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar/#containerstyle) for more props and you can supply your own `Icon`

Comment: you have to add "inputContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}".

Comment: search bar clear button shows only on test type how to show `always`

Answer (score 1):

I made a combination of the answers here

```
 <SearchBar
    inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderRadius: 5}}
    inputContainerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
    placeholderTextColor={'#g5g5g5'}
    placeholder={'Pritish Vaidya'}
```

/>